# Checking the console for whitespaces

Tags: java, java-8, console-application, java.util.scanner

i want to test if the next input is a whitespace, to end a loop for collecting id's provided by the user.

Therefore i use the `hasNext()` function of the `Scanner`. I tried to provide different patterns but non seems to work.

Could this be due to the scanner using the whitespace as default delimiter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scanner's hasNextLine() and nextLine() methods and you'll find your solution since this will allow you to capture empty or white-space lines.

Comment: I mixed up next<Type>() and nextLine(), the parts skipped by next() resulted in the "malfunctional" nextLine()...